# Trying to resize a UITableView to fit screen on iPad

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to resize a simple UITableView that fits between a navigationbar and a tabbar.

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];   

    UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 367.0f) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableview.dataSource = self;
    tableview.delegate = self;
    self.tableView = tableview;
    [tableview release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

I have removed the autoresizing I have been trying to do because it does not work, any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  Create your view programmatically in loadView, do not call [super loadView]

2)  create tableView with size same as application screen, use [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] or something similar

3)  set UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight for tableView

..Edited answer to be more clear..

Comment: I think i'm wrong about having to set autoresizing flags for self.view, since it will be automatically resized by the system, for example when call comes in and statusbar height doubles.  I have exact same tableview setup like yours, with flexibleheight and it changes height accordingly (as long as you fill it same size as self.view initially)..

Comment: I just noticed you are calling [super loadview] - you should never have to call it.  Create your view programmatically, or just do "self.view = self.tableView".  Also, make your tableView frame size as big as screen, since the size you create tableView are for iphone size.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I am fixing that in my code, seems like it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
tableView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the first line, but I did not try the second line in your answer. What does it work?

Comment: Autoresizing mask defines only relative changes of frame. `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` doesn't mean "fill parent vertically", it's "if parent height is changed you should change your height accordingly". It's programmer's responsibility to set up view's size properly either in XIB or programmatically. That's what second line do. After this `tableView` is located at the left corner of parent view and has same size as it.